# Slicing multidimensional table

Tags: data, list-manipulation, filtering

Say I have a multidimensional list created in the following way

```
 grid= 
 Table[{i, j+1, k+2}, {i, 0, 1}, {j, 0, 1}, {k, 0, 1}]
```

```
grid={{{{0, 1, 2}, {0, 1, 3}}, {{0, 2, 2}, {0, 2, 3}}},
      {{{1, 1, 2}, {1, 1, 3}}, {{1, 2, 2}, {1, 2, 3}}}}
```

How can I keep a 2-dimensional slice of this 3-dimensional table, or in general, a 2-dimensional slice of an n-dimensional table?. Say I would like to obtain the array for which the second quantity has the value of 1, i.e.

```
dim=2; (* The dimension I want to eliminate *)
value=1;
out=f[grid,dim,value]
```

```
out={{{0, 2}, {0, 3}}, {{1, 2}, {1, 3}}}
```

I have worked out a rudimentary way of taking 1-D slices from 2-D sets of data, but nothing I have tried works for >2-dimensional tables.

Thank you very much.

Comment: `Part[]` in conjunction with the specification `All` ought to be useful. BTW, `out` is still a 3D array.

Comment: Yes, that is the piece I have obtained right, when using `Part[grid, All, 2, All]` gives me the output I want but still with the column that I want to get rid of, and the problem I am facing is to eliminate that second column. Additionally, I am aware that the output is a 3D array, since I need sort of a "2D array for which each element is a two-coordinate vector".

Comment: @pepeperez You really need to be careful, what you ask for. You have an array of the form `a[i, j, k]` and you want to take a slice, eliminating the second dimension? That implies getting the array `a[i, j0, k]` where `j0` is a fixed number. What you're being given in the answers is not a 2D slice, but rather a still 3D array where in `a[i, j, k]` the 3rd dimension `k` skips over the value `2`.

Comment: @LLlAMnYP let me see if I can be more explicit: my array `grid` is a `2x2x2` matrix in which each element is a 3-vector. My intention is to choose a particular value of one of the parameters (say, first parameter being `0`) and choose all the values vectors, still in matrix form, that satisfy the condition. This gives me a `2x2` matrix in which each element is a 3-vector with `0` as the first value. Finally, I want to eliminate the first value of each vector in this `2x2` matrix, since it is not relevant any more. You mean that this is not what the answer below is doing?

Comment: By coincidence, it so happens, that all the vectors with `0` as their first element are restricted to `a[1, j, k]`. Yes, this is what's being done. Otherwise you could end up with a case where the resulting nested list of vectors is 3D. I have an answer coming up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's an answer to the question in the comments below OP:

```
grid={{{{0, 1, 2}, {0, 1, 3}}, {{0, 2, 2}, {0, 2, 3}}},
      {{{1, 1, 2}, {1, 1, 3}}, {{1, 2, 2}, {1, 2, 3}}}}
```

A `2x2x2` list of 3-component vectors.

If I understood correctly, *pick out, for example, all such vectors, that have `0` as their first component*. I am inclined to take a pattern-matching approach.

```
grid /. Except[{0, _, _}, {_, _, _}] -> 
         Unevaluated[Sequence[]] //.
          {} -> Unevaluated[Sequence[]] //.
           {a_List} :> a
```

First line reads "take grid and replace everything that matches a 3-component vector, *except* a vector with `0` at the start with..."

Second line: "...a so called *vanishing function*. Then repeatedly apply the following rule until nothing changes..."

Third line: "...the rule is to replace empty lists with the same vanishing function. Finally repeatedly apply the rule..."

Fourth line: "...of replacing any list that is the only element of a parent list with itself".

> `{{{0, 1, 2}, {0, 1, 3}}, {{0, 2, 2}, {0, 2, 3}}}`

Because otherwise we would get a `1x2x2` grid instead of a `2x2` grid. But if we have a different grid:

```
grid = {{{{0, 1, 2}, {0, 1, 3}}, {{0, 2, 2}, {0, 2, 3}}}, 
        {{{0, 1, 2}, {1, 1, 3}}, {{1, 2, 2}, {1, 2, 3}}}}
```

> `{{{{0, 1, 2}, {0, 1, 3}}, {{0, 2, 2}, {0, 2, 3}}}, {0, 1, 2}}`

Not so great. Still a 3D grid, also the last vector is at a different depth than the others. But here we can drop the last of the replacement rules:

```
grid /.
  Except[{0, _, _}, {_, _, _}] -> Unevaluated[Sequence[]] //.
   {} -> Unevaluated[Sequence[]]
```

> `{{{{0, 1, 2}, {0, 1, 3}}, {{0, 2, 2}, {0, 2, 3}}}, {{{0, 1, 2}}}}`

Anyway, whatever the output, a final replacement rule to drop the `0`s:

```
% /. {0, a_, b_} :> {a, b}
```

> `{{{{1, 2}, {1, 3}}, {{2, 2}, {2, 3}}}, {{{1, 2}}}}`

or with the original `grid` and result of its processing:

> `{{{1, 2}, {1, 3}}, {{2, 2}, {2, 3}}}`

**Update**

This is largely guesswork, but the way your grid is structured is suggestive.

There's a great answer somewhere here about using `Flatten` with a matrix as the second argument.

This command gives all possible usage options that are applicable for your case ordered in a nice way.

```
MatrixForm /@ First /@ (Flatten[grid, #] & /@ Permutations[{{1}, {2}, {3}}])
```

The way your grid is structured,

```
First@Flatten[grid,{{i},{j},{k}}]
```

returns the four vectors with matching `i`-th elements, and depending on the order of `j` and `k` they are arranged as `{{1,2},{3,4}}` or `{{1,3},{2,4}}`.

So you can also try

```
(First@Flatten[grid,{{i},{j},{k}}])[[All,All,{j,k}]]
```

e.g.

```
(First@Flatten[grid, {{1}, {2}, {3}}])[[All, All, {2, 3}]]
```

> `{{{1, 2}, {1, 3}}, {{2, 2}, {2, 3}}}`

Comment: Yes, I believe this is the answer to my problem. Thank you very much for your help and the time you have deposited.

Comment: Thanks for the accept, but maybe there's a much better solution to your problem that someone would be now discouraged to post. In fact I have a great idea with `Flatten`.

Comment: Probably you want to "unaccept" the answer to encourage people to work on it? I would be happy to do that if you agree, sorry but I am quite new around here.

Comment: Yeah, that's I meant :-)

Answer (score 3):

```
Pick[#[[All, {1, 3}]], #[[All, 2]], 1] & @@@ grid
(* {{{0, 2}, {0, 3}}, {{1, 2}, {1, 3}}} *)
```

or

```
(Select[#, #[[2]] == 1 &] & @@@ grid)[[All, All , {1, 3}]]
(* {{{0, 2}, {0, 3}}, {{1, 2}, {1, 3}}} *)
```

or

```
Cases[grid, m : {{_, 1, _} ..} :> m[[All, {1, 3}]], {2}]
(* {{{0, 2}, {0, 3}}, {{1, 2}, {1, 3}}} *)
```

**Update:** You can also turn the methods above into functions:

```
pF[g_, keep_, drop_, val_] := Pick[#[[All, keep]], #[[All, drop]], val] & @@@ g

sF[g_, keep_, drop_, val_] := (Select[#, #[[drop]] == val &] & @@@ g)[[All, All, keep]]

cF[g_, keep_, drop_, val_] := Cases[g, m : {RotateRight[{val, _, _}, drop - 1] ..} :> 
   m[[All, keep]], {2}]
```

Examples:

```
pF[grid, {1, 3}, 2, 1]
(* {{{0, 2}, {0, 3}}, {{1, 2}, {1, 3}}} *)

pF[grid, {1, 2}, 3, 3]
(* {{{0, 1}}, {{1, 1}}} *)
```

Comment: Thank you @kguler for your great answer. Nevertheless, I still have some questions. Say that now I want to obtain the slice for which the first quantity has the value of 0, how should I modify the above codes to do so?

Comment: pepeperez, does  `Pick[#[[All, {1, 3}]], #[[All, 1]], 0] & @@@ grid` give the desired output? or `Pick[#[[All, {2, 3}]], #[[All, 1]], 0] & @@@ grid`?

Comment: Not quite, but almost. The first one gives `{{{0, 2}, {0, 3}}, {}}`, and the second one, `{{{1, 2}, {1, 3}}, {}}`, which is the first part of the desired solution, which would be `{{{1, 2}, {1, 3}}, {2, 2}, {2, 3}}}`

Comment: peperez, `cF[grid, {2, 3}, 1, 0]` gives the correct output. I will fix the ones with `Pick` and `Select`.

Comment: kguler, thank you very much again. Indeed, `cF` gives the correct output for the first two columns, but both `cF[grid, {1, 2}, 3, 2]` and `cF[grid, {1, 2}, 3, 3]` give as result `{}`

Comment: pepeperez, what is the expected output for `cF[grid, {1, 2}, 3, 2]` and `cF[grid, {1, 2}, 3, 3]`?

Comment: kguler, the expected output for both of them is `{{{0, 1}, {0, 2}}, {{1, 1}, {1, 2}}}`